# shell_exec(php -v) returns different version to php -v ran in Terminal

Tags: php, bash, macos, shell, path

This is what is displayed when I run it in the Terminal on macOS Sierra

```
php -v

PHP 7.0.15 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2017 10:30:54) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies 
    with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

When I run the command using shell_exec in PHP I get a different result

```
echo shell_exec("php -v");

PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb 7 2017 16:18:37) Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Even when I run phpversion from the same file as shell_exec I get a different result

```
echo phpversion();

7.0.15
```

I've searched for hours trying to figure out how to tell shell_exec to point to the correct version of PHP which is at located at

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php
```

But it always seems to use the preinstalled version located at

```
/usr/bin/php
```

My bash profile is as follows

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile

export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Any advice or help would be really appreciated as this problem has me totally confused.

Comment: Just curious, why execute the PHP executable from within PHP?

Comment: by any chance, are you `shell_exec`'ing from an http process of some kind?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I have a file info.php and I calling that from http://localhost/info.php

Comment: @MattS I use shell_exec with PHP to call other PHP scripts that I need to run in the background

Comment: Your `whatever http server` must be configured with the default (brain-dead, imnsho) distro configuration of your (unspecified) osx. Did you brew php ? What http server are you using, etc.

Comment: If my Unix is no too rusty (and works in Mac) you can get the full path from a command with `which`, e.g. `which php`. You can also try `echo $PATH`.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: I was going in the same direction.  If your PHP runs inside Apache, then the environment used by Apache is what the PHP code uses under Apache.  It is probable that the Apache user has a different PATH then your user.  As Alvaro pointed out, you can use the which command to know where php is.  Or force the full path you want in shell_exec.

Comment: There are much better ways to run background processes.  I suggest pushing messages to a queue and running a PHP daemon to process them.

Comment: @Nic is there any way of editing the PATH for this Apache user. If that's not possible I can edit the command to give it full path to the correct php version but I'd prefer not to have to do this.

Comment: The PATH value Apache will use is based on the user running it.  so you could modify that user's PATH value like you did for yours (.bash_profile).  But you need full access to that user.  Otherwise, full path call it is :-)

Comment: @MattS I had a feeling it wasn't done particularly well and it could definitely do with being rewritten so thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Nic From what I can see it is the user _www that runs Apache so I ran sudo -u _www -s to switch to that user in the Terminal but when I run php -v it gives me the correct version and not the one shown when shell_exec("php -v") is ran

Comment: Ok... how about shell_exec("which php");  Looks more and more like you will have to force the path!

Comment: @Nic that returns /usr/bin/php but if I run that command in the terminal I get /usr/local/php5/bin/php

Comment: I ran the command id in the Terminal and using shell_exec and it gave me the same user, me.

Comment: Ok so we know for sure that the Apache PHP is not the same you are using.  Full Path it is I think.